# Что произойдет если прописать некорректное значение в .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, php.ini

Большинство из вас прекрасно понимают как работают функции в различных языках программирования, один момент из всей кучи - возврат значения. То есть мы можем вызвать допустим функцию `intval()` - возвращает целое число, а принимает что попало! Есть такие моменты что при неправильном аргументе функция может выдать специальный ответ.

Так вот подходим к сути вопроса, есть у нас файл `.htaccess` и в нем строчка, она может быть любой! В данном случае я захотел написать это `php_value output_buffering blablabla`. Как на такую строку отреагирует apache?

**Дополнительная информация:**

`php.ini`:

```
output_buffering=On
```

---

**php.ini:** `output_buffering=On`

**Вариант 1:**

`.htaccess`

```
php_value output_buffering blablabla
```

отключенный буфер

**Вариант 2:**

`.htaccess`

```
php_value output_buffering 4096
```

включенный буфер

---

**php.ini:** `output_buffering=off`

**Вариант 1:**

`.htaccess`

```
php_value output_buffering blablabla
```

отключенный буфер

**Вариант 2:**

`.htaccess`

```
php_value output_buffering 4096
```

включенный буфер

**Вывод:** ответы идентичны, хотя когда `output_buffering=On` и мы пишем в `.htaccess` мусор мы получаем деактивацию...почему?

Comment: При ошибке в htaccess apache2 обычно возвращает код ошибки 500

Comment: Вы можете попробовать и посмотреть на результат прежде чем задавать вопрос.

Comment: @Alex Я пробовал, но я не удовлетворен тем что я получил на выходе и это не ошибка с номером 500

Comment: @MaximPro в таком случае рекомендуем указывать в вопросе информацию о том, что Вы пробовали и о том, что получили. Но ведь если Вы что-то получили, в чем тогда вопрос? может быть Вам стоит переформулировать его?

Comment: вопрос в заголовке и в самом вопросе имеет разный смысл.

Comment: `принимает что попало` - в языках со строгой типизацией принимает не что попало, а только определённый тип или интерфейс. `при неправильном аргументе функция может выдать специальный ответ` — любое поведение кроме сообщения об ошибке (исключения и т.п.) обычно считается багом. Если вы нашли значение, при котором не 500 и не чистый лист, а (что?), то имеет смысл зарепортить баг разработчикам апача.

Comment: Кстати, рассматривать http-сервер как функцию, а его конфиг как аргумент не совсем корректно. Вам что-то там возвращается всё-таки на http-запрос, а не на конфиг.

Comment: Обновил пост...

Answer (score 2):

- У вас появится страница с ошибкой 500.
- Либо "чистый лист", зависит от настроек.

.

Comment: Вы не угадали! Ни то ни другое!

Comment: Мы тут не на программе что где когда.  Мы тут не гадаем а делимся опытом и решаем вопросы. Если в вашем вопросе есть скрытый смысл, тогда мне нечего ответить более.

Comment: у nginx есть параметр `nginx -t`, по которому nginx проверяет конфиг и возвращает результат. Наверняка и у апача что-то такое есть?

Comment: Да ладно, чего вы такой серьезный? Надо спокойнее подходить к вопросу. Я к чему вообще спросил?! Для того чтобы узнать что вернет директива `php_value`? Но как вы написали - совсем не то что я получил. В моем случае когда я писал ерунду, у меня данная директива принимала значение 0. Как это объяснить я затрудняюсь!

Comment: Обновил пост, можете поглядеть, если что-то знаете по данному поводу напишите

Comment: что же это значит. вернет директива  `php_value` как директива может что то вернуть?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь это так условности, конечно директива ничего не вернет, мне интересно как она влияет на конфигурации apache

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь вызвал функцию `phpinfo()` в php файле, нашел строку `output_buffering` и там увидел значения `Local Value` и `Master Value`, то что я записывал в `.htaccess` файл отображалось `Local Value` то что было в `php.ini` было отображено в `Master Value`. В `Local Value` записывалось то что я писал, даже текстовый мусор. Но влияние на эту директиву было никакое, точнее директива принимала значение 0, из-за мусора, это можно было проверить в php файле вызвав функцию `ob_get_level()`. P.S Мне нужно обяснение почему директива видя строку не принимает ее и пишет 0?

Comment: Почему вопрос адресован именно мне? Может стоит обратиться к сорсам PHP или Расмусу Лердорфу?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь так вы же отвечаете мне на вопрос или не?
И что значит: `Либо "чистый лист", зависит от настроек.`?

Comment: многие называют в качестве симптомов чистый лист, т.е. белый экран в браузере, что чаще всего означает что вывод ошибок отключен с целью повышения безопасности.